# How to use np.where nested in data frame with pandas?

Tags: pandas

I want to implement a logic to add a custom label based on the following criteria:

```
if df[(df['value1'] ==0) & (df['value2']==1)] then label1
if df[(df['value1'] ==0) & (df['value2']==0)] then label2
if df[(df['value1'] ==1) & (df['value2']==1)] then label3
if df[(df['value1'] ==1) & (df['value2']==0)] then label4
```

Out:

```
label_class | other columns
label1      |...
label1      |...
label3      |...
label2      |...
```

I tried with np.where but I am not sure how to do the nesting properly.

Comment: can you also provide your initial df? (df.head().to_dict('records'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = (df['value1'] ==0) & (df['value2']==1)
m2 = (df['value1'] ==0) & (df['value2']==0)
m3 = (df['value1'] ==1) & (df['value2']==1)
m4 = (df['value1'] ==1) & (df['value2']==0)
labels = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4']

df['label_class'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3, m4], labels)
```

Another idea is create helper DataFrame by all combinatons and labels and then add to DataFrame by left join:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value1':[0,0,1,1], 'value2':[1,0,1,0], 'label_class':labels})

df = df.merge(df1, on=['value1','value2'], how='left')
```

Idea with mapping by both columns:

```
d = {(0, 1): 'label1', (0, 0): 'label2', (1, 1): 'label3', (1, 0): 'label4'}

df['label_class'] = df.set_index(['value1','value2']).index.map(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is in this way `np.where(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

In you case, you can do it in this way:

```
np.where(df[(df['value1'] ==0) & (df['value2']==1)], 'label1',
         np.where(if df[(df['value1'] ==0) & (df['value2']==0)], 'label2',
         np.where(if df[(df['value1'] ==1) & (df['value2']==1)], 'label3',
         np.where(if df[(df['value1'] ==1) & (df['value2']==0)], 'label4', None))))
```